# How to interrupt a read of a lexical filehandle in Perl?

Tags: perl, timeout

As far as I know, the pattern for interrupting something after some time in Perl, is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "timed out\n"; };
my $pid;
eval {
    alarm 10;
    # do stuff
    alarm 0;
};
print "done\n";
kill(9, $pid) if $pid;
```

So one example of a "something" is opening a subprocess for reading which might randomly hang. Simulating it for testing purposes works as expected:

```
# replace "# do stuff" with:
    $pid = open FH, "sleep 120|";
    my $line = <FH>;
    close FH;
```

However, these globally-named things can't be passed to other subroutines, so I really want to use the following implementation:

```
# replace "# do stuff" with:
    $pid = open my $fh, "sleep 120|";
    my $line = <$fh>;
    close $fh;
```

... but when I run this, the Perl script hangs indefinitely! Why?

Comment: Interesting case.. The lexical file handle case works (alarm is triggered after 10s) for me (using perl 5.34.0) if I declare `$fh` outside (and before) the `eval` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there are no references left to a variable (perhaps as a result of it going out of scope), Perl cleans up the resources associated with that variable. Destructors are called, memory is freed, file handles are closed, etc. This is the case even if the variable ceases to be referenced due to an exception.

When a file handle created using `open -|` or `open |-` is closed, Perl waits for the child process to end. This happens not just for explicit calls to `close`, but for implicit closes that happen as a result of the destroying an open file handle.

In your scenario, Perl is waiting for the child to complete as a result of the implicit close of the file handle. It doesn't hang indefinitely, but for the remainder of the 120 seconds it takes for the child to end. This is the behaviour one should observe for both versions of the program, and it is the behaviour one observes for both versions unless one is using an old version of Perl. Up until the release of 5.18 9 years ago, a bug skipped closing of file handles during global destruction.

Comment: 1. There's an `eval` here; does that change anything about the "global" in "global destruction"?



2. What you're saying is that there is no reliable way to stop a misbehaving subprocess from hanging the entire interpreter, if one wants to stream-in the subprocess's output when it doesn't misbehave?

Comment: 1) No. It just means the destruction happens before `eval` exits rather than before the program does. 2) Absolutely not. I'm saying the code you have waits for the child to end, which is why it hangs <strike>indefinitely</strike>until the child exits.

Comment: So I replaced the line with `<$fh>` with an invocation of `die`. It exited after running far less than 2 seconds. Why doesn't this contradict your hypothesis?

Comment: 1) It's not a hypothesis. 2) The `eval` returns 10 seconds later, not 2. The fact that it doesn't return immediately is consistent with my explanation: The implicit close is waiting for the child to exit. If this wait didn't occur, `eval` would return immediately after `die` is called.  In this new scenario, the signal comes in when waiting for the child to end, so it's the wait that's interrupted rather than the read.

Comment: @ikegami *"Perl waits for the child process to end"* When I test this with perl 5.34, it does not seem like perl waits when using bareword filehandle. I observe the same behavior as OP, the program terminates after 10 seconds in that case.

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, I don't know why you'd still have the bug in 5.34. Or maybe something else is different? Please provide your program.

Comment: @ikegami Here is my test program: https://pastebin.com/dA3ipYZ2, The output is `elapsed = 10` when using lexical handle and `elapsed = 5` when using bare word file handle.

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, There's no wait because you kill the child process before the wait would occur. Or rather, there's still a call to `waitpid`, but it returned immediately because you previously killed the child. It's your addition of `kill` that's the difference. You seem to have forgotten that `FH` is freed when `perl` exits, not when the `eval` exits.

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, Note that the bug was an optimization of global destruction. So using `local *FH` won't produce the bug even pre 5.18.  And I think keeping a lexical alive until global destruction (`{ my $x = [ $fh ]; push @$x, $x; }`) would cause the bug to manifest itself (pre 5.18). The difference isn't package variable vs lexical variable, the difference is when the variable is freed.

Comment: Also note that file scope is a lexical scope cleaned up before global destruction, so moving `my $fh` to the top level isn't enough. Global destruction is when the symbol table is freed, and also memory cycles.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for clearifying.. I think I see the problem more clearly now. If the OP wants to kill the child before the destroctor cleans up the handle and starts waiting for the child, he needs to either kill the child in the ALRM signal handler or declare the lexical handle outside the `eval` block and then kill the child after the block as they are doing now...

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, They could also wrap the handle is an object with a destructor that kills the child. There's no option to proceed without waiting for the child to end when using `open -|` and `open |-`. Could use IPC::Run if that's what you want to do.